# How to pass two-dimensional array to fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

I use android navigation to switch fragments. I want to pass something like `ArrayList<ArrayList<MyParcelable>>` within `Bundle`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

`Bundle` is a key-value store that accommodates many data structures out of the box. However for something as specific as `ArrayList<ArrayList<MyParcelable>>` I would recommend serializing the object (JSON) to package it with the Bundle, then deserializing it on the other end.